# How to trick the OS to see a hostname as another

Tags: linux, networking, configuration, docker

I have 3 machines:

```
A.local ---> B.example.com
        ---> C.local
```

`C.local` is a Docker container running a service on port `5000` (a local Docker registry) that proxies `B.example.com` (a remote Docker registry).

**How can I configure A so that instead it resolves/connects to `C.local` when trying to reach `B.example.com`?**

I am not sure if this is possible at all and at what OSI layer. I thought to use `/etc/host` but that's just for DNS to assign hardcoded IP addresses.
Would `iptables` be enough?

The result should be that A sees B as `original-B.example.com` and replaces it with C, that is seen as `B.example.com`.
This way it should connect to `C.local:5000` when trying to connect to `B.example.com` (on port 443, [if I understood correctly](https://docs.docker.com/registry/configuration/#letsencrypt))

Answer (score 0):

If you have SSH on all three machines you could do this:

```
user@A.local $ ssh -J B.example.com -L 5555:127.0.0.1:5000 C.local
```

With that connection active, you can connect to `C.local:5000` by accessing `127.0.0.1:5555` (5555 is arbitrary).

Breakdown

- [`ssh`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh)
- `-J B.example.com`: Proxy-jump through B.example.com (you'll need to login to B before being forwarded to C)
- `-L 5555:127.0.0.1:5000`, bind local port `127.0.0.1:5555` to final destination port 5000.
- `C.local`: Final destination